# Draw 3d Inequality on Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm struggling to draw an inequality on Matlab. I need to draw a 3d dimensional space using the following constrains and function.The functions that I have are:

```
x>=5,000
y>=7,000
z>=3,000
3x+2y+5z<=53,000
```

And I can't come up with any idea how to do that, help will be very appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how much work you can do before writing code there are different ways to do this. The simplest is this:

```
x=linspace(5000,53000/3); % create vectors for possible values of each variable
y=linspace(7000,53000/2);
z=linspace(3000,53000/5);
[X,Y,Z]=meshgrid(x,y,z);
I=(X>=5000) & (Y>=7000) & (Z>=3000) & (3*X+2*Y+5*Z<=53000); % combine all constraints
scatter3(X(I),Y(I),Z(I),'filled') % scatter plot, has many options which may prove useful
```